# Setting border color for new Image() in javascript inside a canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i set a border-color for an image variable in javascript ?

```
var img= new Image();
  img.onload=function(){
    // how can i set the border color 
  };
 img.src="url.png";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H2k5W/61/

Comment: `img.style.borderColor = 'color';`?

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: If you don't append the image anywhere, it's normal that it is not shown. Moreover you're not setting any type of border to the image, just its color.

Answer (score 1):

do something like:

```
var image = new Image(); 
image.src = 'http://www.google.com/logos/2011/guitar11-hp-sprite.png';
image.onload = function(){
    alert("loaded");
    image.style.border='1px solid black';
};
var divele = document.getElementById("test");
divele.appendChild(image);
```

Demo ::[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpWBp/)

Comment: the thing is that i am using a canvas and the image is inside the canvas i'll edit my jsfiddle